Microsoft.Data.SqlClient vs System.Data.SqlClient - output directory
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            var c = new SqlConnection();
        }
    }
}

after compile produces this:

But this:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            var c = new SqlConnection();
        }
    }
}

after compile produces this:

And now two questions:

Do I have to distribute all produced files with my app ?

Is there a way to limit files produces by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient ? With other Db libraries (Firebird, Odbc) there is only one file XXX.Data.XClient.dll


I dont want to use publishing to single file, because it is huge.
I was trying to delete some of them, bo it looks like many of them are required.

1: Yes. 2: Not unless you use single-file publishing or native AoT compilation.

Some dependency aren't needed when you target a more current net version directly. But the dependency on Azure/Microsoft assemblies will stay. You might ignore the localization assemblies/folders if you think you don't need translated error messages.

There is no way to distribute only ConsoleApp2.* files ? I mean - can Microsoft.Data.SqlClient be installed somewhere else on target machine ? That sounds horrible that i have to put all those files into my installer :/

What is so horrible about that? That it looks big and when putting parts somewhere else it looks small to the naive user?

@Ralf: I just fill strange about that. Giving end user 200 files where im author only of one : ) When i write another small app - then i have to put the same files to directory of the second app ? It smells like redundancy to me - but im newbie in .net, maybe thats normal. What about case when i want to have one folder in which i put my two console apps - can those file by shared ? What will happen when those file will have different version ... Long long time ago there was a term 'Dll hell'.

And that never changed there is still that hell. You can just choose the flavor of that hell. Just deploying the needed assemblies in one folder is the easiest to understand/maintain and create installers for. If you want stuff to be somewhere else you are in charge of finding them for your executable, making sure not colliding with other apps making sure you don't create additional security risks by that etc.

If you have 2 installers for 2 apps just don't install in the same folder. That creates another layer of hell at the latest when trying to uninstall one without breaking the other. Only have more then one app in one folder when they are installed together by the same installer.

So what is the correct way to publish solution that contains one class library (.dll) and two console apps (.exe) (both of them use mentioned class library) ? Should i have one commom publish folder for that ? And then put all files from that folder to installer ? I don't see something like "Publish all" in solution context menu. I have to click publish separately for each project ? I guess in publish dialog i should use same settings ?

In the case of the first question, it is better to distribute all the content, and in the case of the second question, it is better to review the references of your project and delete the unnecessary ones
